# MySql DB with ext3 and XFS

Tags: mysql

Is there any advantage for XFS file system compared with ext3, With MYSQL DB ?

Which is safest file system for hosting MYSQL DB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XFS was designed to handle large files efficiently. This could be an advantage if your database is very large or if all of your tables are stored in InnoDB format (since the data then resides in one large file). In consequence, you should get a performance boost out of it.

I cannot really make a judgement on the safety of any particular file system, other than the general comment that running any database without appropriate backups is madness. Also, in a production system I would ***NEVER*** run a database on anything else but a RAID array.

Comment: Sure .. We are with the RAID 5 and having the replica as well as the daily backup. With googling I can see the XFS is much faster than ext3, and further reading I think ext-4 can be better with considering safety with performance (Journal checksumming).